# Fatal error: Class 'Nik_Newsletterpopup_Helper_Data' not found in Mage.php on line 547

Tags: php, magento

I am using Magento Community V1.9. After I installed one extension 'Newsletter Subscription with Discount Coupon', when I tried to enter the backend.

I found a error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Nik_Newsletterpopup_Helper_Data' not found in
>   Mage.php on line 547.

The frontend and other moduel in backend work correctly. Only `System->Configuration` has such error.

I checked the similar problems and answers in StackOverFlow. But the problem is still here.

Data.php is in the right path (`/app/code/local/Nik/Newsletterpopup/Helper`), and the class is declared in config.xml also.

Could anyone can help me on that? Thank you very much!

Here is the code in Config.xml:

```
    <helpers>
        <newsletterpopup>
            <class>Nik_Newsletterpopup_Helper</class>
        </newsletterpopup>
    </helpers>
```

Comment: Hi guys, we found more information. If enable 'Compilation', after we install the extension, we can not enter system->Configuration. But if disable 'Comilation', the extension works well. 
What's the real reason about this?

Answer (score 0):

- Check that the Nik > Newsletterpopup module is enabled under Configuration > Advanced > Advanced.  If it's not listed there, you may be missing the xml file to register the module in /app/etc/modules/
- Check the class name inside the /app/code/local/Nik/Newsletterpopup/Helper/Data.php file to make sure that it is Nik_Newsletterpopup_Helper_Data

Comment: The class name inside the /app/code/local/Nik/Newsletterpopup/Helper/Data.php file is Nik_Newsletterpopup_Helper_Data.

For the first item. We can not check, because we can not enter to System->Configuration after the extension installation.

Comment: After we disable "Compliation" function, we can enter in "Configuration > Advanced > Advanced", the module  Newsletterpopup is enabled. In /app/etc/modules/, we have Nik_Newsletterpopup.xml.

Answer (score 0):

in include src folder all the files are placed when compilation is set to true.

If you installed module later or for some reason  files of module in question are not in include/src folder then Magento will assume this file as not found and throw error.

So do check include/src folder for this specific file.

Comment: I checked inlude/src folder, there is no Nik folder. I think the reason should be Compliation conflict with Nik_Newsletterpopup extension. But I do not know how to solve it. One more information is: even we disable Compliation, Nik_Newsletterpopup does not work. The only diffrence is we can enter System->Configuration if we disable Compliation. Thank you!

Comment: Did you flush cache after setting compilation to No.

Comment: Also paste config.xml of related modules.

Comment: Yes. We flushed cache after setting compliation to No. Where should we paste config.xml to?